Manimgl (manimlib) Function Calling Error
I’m trying to make animations using Python Manimgl (3b1b) module, but I have some problems. As an unexperienced Manim user studying github codes I faced the following problem that I’m unable to solve:
Code
I would like to call a function to my code (yellow box in the below figure) from another folder (blue box) I previously prepared. But I get the following error every time:
Error
I couldn’t find a solution after struggling for weeks so I will appreciate any help on this issue.
P.S.1. All the functions in two folders work when I include them in one .py folder but the problem occurs when I try to separate them and call one from the other.
P.S.2. Forgive me if my problem seems so simple or meaningless to you as I’m trying to learn coding by myself and literally from scratch.
Thanks in advance.
Call and run a function in my code (.py) from another folder (.py) I previously prepared.

The code should be posted as text, not a screenshot
